# Is there a way to set different orientation to different screens in kivy?

Tags: kivy

I have this app that has two screens only. The second screen needs to be in landscape while the first in portrait. Is that possible in kivy, if yes how would I go about programming that?

Comment: android or ios?

Comment: @eyllanesc - Both ...

Comment: That depends on each OS, so I recommend that you just indicate one.

Comment: @eyllanesc - Well since I don't have an iOs right now let's try on android. How would it be done please?

Comment: The start screen portrait and the second landscape. How could I accomplish that, please?